# Dual cursors in twin Tkinter Canvases

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got two Canvases displaying images (one is the source, and the other is slightly modified). 
I'd like to sync both Canvases' cursors, i.e when hovering over one, a cursor will also show on the other in the same position.
I've already done this by drawing a custom 'plus' cursor (2 intersecting lines), but I'm not satisfied with the result.
Is there a way to 'fake' the mouse hovering over the canvas at a certain position?

Edit:
My relevant code, as per request:

```
self.canvas_image.bind("<Motion>", self.processMouseEvent)

def processMouseEvent(self): 
     self.cursorSync.Sync(event)
```

Comment: Showing tne `Sync` function is probably more useful than showing how it is bound to an event.

Comment: When you say you are not satisfied, what is it you are unhappy with? Does it look bad? Does it perform poorly? What problem are we tackling here?

Comment: Sync function currently draws 2 lines on a canvas. I already know how to do this, and it works fine, so I don't need any input or comments on that code. That is why I don't show it. The answer I'm looking for doesn't have anything to do with anything in .Sync as it is now. I thought the request to see my code unnecessary, since I did't ask for fixes, but for an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to have more than one cursor active at a time. Your only option is to simulate a second cursor by either drawing one on the canvas, or using a small widget that you place over the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

The `Motion` event will have an x,y attribute assigned to it. Why not do something like this, where your cursor could be any object that can be managed by the `place` geometry manager:

```
def move_cursor(event):
    cursor.place(x=event.x, y=event.y) # set x,y to cursor

root = Tk()

left = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100, bg='white')
right = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100, bg='black')
left.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=LEFT)
right.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=RIGHT)

cursor = Label(right, width=2, bg='red') # create cursor. this could be an image or whatever

left.bind('<Motion>', move_cursor)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Why use a widget and `place`? This is a canvas -- you can draw anything you want, and aren't confined to rectangles.

Comment: This is similar to what I did earlier, minus the drawing (is placing labels more efficient?).
Anyway, its not exactly what I was looking for, as this isn't placing a cursor, but rather imitating one.
But still, thanks.

Comment: @BryanOakley, just seems simpler to do it like that to me, I don't use canvas much. @YonadavSchleifer, you could add a binding to `Button-1` to imitate a mouse click, and whatever else you need. I can't speak to efficiency of the place vs. canvas drawing, but personally I think it's more readable. If your end goal is to use an image of a cursor, I think either way would work fine.

Comment: On second thought, you could probably get more mileage out of a canvas object. Maybe. I guess it depends on what you need it to do.